# How to improve performance in Multi-thread way for using OrientDB？

Tags: java, multithreading, orientdb

I got something wrong in multi-thread way to using OrientDB.

They have total 20k records in the database and I want get the Top 200 records per thread.

If use one thread at a time I can get the result in 0,5 sec but when I use 10 threads at a time I will get all the result in 5 sec.

More threads will cost more times, 50 threads will cost 50 sec. That's too much time for API reply.

How can I improve the performance of using OrientDB?

I've already have read the document of the OrientDB about Performance-Tuning. I have tried update the parameters about Network Connection Pool but It was useless.

The version of OrientDB is 2.2.37 with single instance.

There have some code sample, just read the record.

```
public class Test3 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        OServerAdmin serverAdmin = new OServerAdmin("remote:localhost").connect("root", "root");

        if (!serverAdmin.existsDatabase("metadata", "plocal")) {
            serverAdmin.createDatabase("metadata", "graph", "plocal");
        }
        serverAdmin.close();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    OrientGraphFactory factory= new OrientGraphFactory("remote:localhost/metadata", "root", "root");
    factory.setAutoStartTx(false);
    factory.setProperty("minPool", 5);
    factory.setProperty("maxPool", 50);
    factory.setupPool(5, 50);;

   int threadCount = 5;
   for (int i = 0; i < threadCount; i++) {
       new Thread(() -> {
           long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
           OrientGraph orientGraph = factory.getTx();
           String sql = "select * from mytable skip 0 limit 100";
           Iterable<Vertex> vertices = orientGraph.command(new OCommandSQL(sql.toString())).execute();
           System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "===" + "execute sql cost:" + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));
       }).start();;
   }
}
}
```

Comment: Hi there! Welcome to stackoverflow! [Here is a resource for "How to ask a good question"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [here is a resource how much code to provide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Remember, stackoverflow is not a code writing service.

Comment: Hi SimonWang, which version of OrientDB you use? Have you tried with single instance or distributed?

Comment: Hi there,I have update the version infomation in the question.

Comment: Are you running embedded ore remote? can you show some code? Are you writing or reading or both?